# How to use miniclip algorithm in a TIc-Tac-Toe game(X0) php

Tags: php, algorithm

Hi I am working on a online TIc-Tac-Toe game using the miniclip algorithm to calculate the best move.I found few examples but i really don't understand the miniclips logic.Some example would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the minimax algorithm?  Can you provide some context, like links to the resources you've used so far?

Answer (score 1):

For a game with such a small number of possible states as Tic-Tac-Toe, it's quite feasible to just build a tree of all possible game states and have your AI only take branches that don't end in a loss.

Beyond that, I think what you're looking for is called [minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), and there's an [article here](http://www.angelfire.com/wi/wickmann/cs002.html) that explains a variation of it in the context of Tic-Tac-Toe.

Comment: Yeah - I think Miniclip.com is the Flash games site my kid spend all their time on. Not me, though. Well, not often.

I think he should look into alpha-beta pruning (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning) as well, to improve that Tic-Tac-Toe performance.

Comment: Yeah, I came across that site in my search. Bookmarked for later.  Alpha-beta pruning is a good idea from an academic standpoint, but not really necessary for tic-tac-toe.  AB pruning is also definitely needed for more complex games like checkers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Decision tree or more like [game tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_tree) is what you're looking for